# making textinput widget on the basis of items in list in a popup and reading the text in in it using kivy framework-

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

```
   def get_credential_fields_for_popup_success(self, urlrequest, data):
        # print(data)
        # print(data['fields'])
        s = list(data['fields'].values())
        # print(s)
        r = list(s[0].values())
        # print(r)
        c = list(r[0].values())
        # print(c)
        list_of_widget = []
        for i in c[0]:
            s = list(i.values())
            list_of_widget.append(s)
        real_list = []
        for i in list_of_widget:
            # print(i[0])
            real_list.append(i[0])

        self.widgets = real_list
        # print(real_list)

    def OpenPopupWindow(self):
        self.layout = GridLayout(rows=len(self.widgets) + 1)
        #count = 0
        for i in range(0, len(self.widgets)):
            self.arr = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
            name = self.arr[i]
            name= ObjectProperty(None)
            print(name)
            if i == 0 :
                self.label = MDLabel(text = self.widgets[i])
                self.name = TextInput(text="", multiline=False, hint_text=self.widgets[i])
                #print(self.widget_name.text)
            else  :
                self.label = MDLabel(text= self.widgets[i])
                self.name = TextInput(text="", multiline=False, hint_text=self.widgets[i],password= True)
                #print(self.widget_name.text)
            self.layout.add_widget(self.label)
            self.layout.add_widget(self.name)
            #print(self.ids.layout)
        #for i in range(0, len(self.widgets)):
        #    layout.add_widget()
        self.button = Button(text="Close", size_hint=(0.2, 0.2), pos_hint={'center_x': 0.2, 'center_y': 0.2})
        self.button.bind(on_press= self.cred_save)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.button)
        self.popup = Popup(title="test Popup", content=self.layout, size_hint=(None, None), size=(300, 400),
                           background="atlas://images/my_popup/white (2) (1)",
                           auto_dismiss=True)
        self.popup.open()

        #print(self.ids.1.text)
        #print(self.ids.2.text)
    def cred_save(self,obj):
        #print('name'+self.ids.layout.ids.zero.text)
            #print('name'+self.layout.one.text)
            #print('name'+se    lf.layout.two.text)
        user_id = self.zero.text
        password = self.one.text
        pin = self.two.text
        print(user_id)
        print(password)
        #self.popup.dismiss()

        #print(self.ids.)
        #self.popup.dismiss()
        client_id = self.zero.text
```

Here , I am getting a list whose length will determine the textinput field  in the popup on trigerring the OpenPopupWindow, in this function i made a popup. Inside it , made gridlayout nd binded  input fields , and  i have tried everything to get the text written in input fileds after pressing the button but i am not able to get the text written in other function which i have called on_press the button widget in popup.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: self.widgets = real_list  is the list by clicking a button  which triggers OpenPopupWindow it should open a popup with n no. of widgets (n is length of self.widgets list) of TextInput type , after making this widgets and a button , i binded it into gridlayout because popup only accept one widget, now afterbinding the layout in the popup , it shoes the widgets which i made inside the layout widget, now i enter some text in the textinput widgets and pressed the button and then activated save_cred  function , and in that function i want to print all text which i wrote in textinput widgets